# Using Session State in Web Service to preserve data sent via AJAX with no proxy

Tags: vb.net, web-services, jquery, asmx, session-state

I have a web service which I am trying to use to create a shopping cart. The data is held ona  separate domain to the website displaying it.

I have set up the service as follows:

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class shoppingCart
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod(True)> _
    Public Function addToCart(itemId, qty, singlePrice, singleWeight, isBulk, apiKey)
        ''' do stuff
         Dim shoppingCart = Session("hgPublicCart")
         if shoppingCart is nothing then 
               '' make shopping cart
         else
               '' add to shopping cart
         end if
         return shoppingCart
    End Function
```

Using this AJAX call:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.buyButton', function () {
        // GET DATA OBJECT
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            crossDomain: true,
            data: data
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                // DO STUFF
            }
        });
    });
```

I am able to successfully click on a "Buy Now" button, send the item info to the web service, and create a new shopping cart, then return it to the browser via the data on the remote server and update my page accordingly.

However... if I then try "buy" a second item to add to the shopping cart, which is held as a session variable on the remote server, I just create another new one, and the previous item in my shopping cart is lost.

I can see why this is happening, I think, the session ID is not being maintained across the AJAX call, but I am at a loss as to how to fix it.

This page: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35119/Using-Session-State-in-a-Web-Service

Comes up as the most useful link on Google, but it's not using an AJAX post, ie not a completely client-side post to a remote server, it is creating a session/cookie on the client server. It might be that I have to go that way anyway, but if anyone can point me in the direction of sample code to use a Session State on a remote server, that would be great.

I do not want to use Javascript Cookies.

EDIT: Please note, I know this won't work on < IE10, I am not concerning myself with that for now...

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for the info @JohnSaunders will moving everything to WDF help with this issue?

Comment: I have no idea. It will, however, keep you from making things worse by deliberately using obsolete tools.

Answer (score 0):

To keep session state in ASP.NET (and iis) is necessary to have both client and server configured properly. [ASP.NET Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx) Client identification is done either by per session cookies(sent in each request) or is *Cookieless* and identification is part of URL e.g.:

```
http://localhost/(lit3py55t21z5v55vlm25s55)/Application/SessionState.aspx
```

So if you want to avoid cookies it is necessary to configure server (web.config - see the article) and maintain proper URL. To me is seems cookies are simpler.